# "Constant CRLF already defined" error when using php-resque with Laravel

Tags: php, redis, laravel, resque, php-resque

I'm running `php-resque` together with Laravel 3 on Ubuntu 12.04.

**Problem:** When a job is enqueued in resque, I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception

Message:

Constant CRLF already defined
Location:

/var/www/dev/vendor/chrisboulton/php-resque/lib/Redisent/Redisent.php on line 10
```

What does the error mean and how can we solve it?

**PHP**

```
// Enqueue in Resque        
$data = array(
    'name'                  => $name,
    'email'                 => $email,
    'created_at'            => DB::raw('NOW()')
);
Resque::enqueue('queue', 'exampleWorker', $data);
```

---

However when I try to enqueue a job using `artisan`, it works!

**Task**

```
class Queue_Task
{
    public function run()
    {
        // Autoload composer vendors.
        require path('composer').DS.'autoload.php';

        $args = array('name' => 'John Smith');
        Resque::enqueue('MyAppName', 'ExampleWorker', $args);

        echo "Resque job queued.\n";
        return;
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
PHP Notice:  Constant CRLF already defined in /var/www/dev/vendor/chrisboulton/php-resque/lib/Redisent/Redisent.php on line 10

Notice: Constant CRLF already defined in /var/www/dev/vendor/chrisboulton/php-resque/lib/Redisent/Redisent.php on line 10
Resque job queued.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a guess, but I'd say in `/var/www/dev/vendor/chrisboulton/php-resque/lib/Redisent/Redisent.php` there's a second `define('CRLF', 'something')` on line 10 that should probably be commented out if you want these two pieces of software to work together.

Comment: Why is it that the job can be enqueued successfully using `artisan`?

Comment: @Nyxynyx Because it's only raising a warning, and not a fatal exception.